# Error occurs during connection Snowflake to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I'm trying to connect Snowflake to Power BI I get an error:

"ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL https://eda87722.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=9eb99320-1fc6-49ee-859b-0fca3e70638b&request_guid=5f7d40b7-7025-410c-8905-da5b7e7e78cd&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=5 msg='Couldn't resolve proxy name' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'."

Interesting that I'm able to establish the connection on another machine with no issues. But I can't find the reason for such issue.

What I've tried:

1. Established the connection with vpn on and vpn off - no difference
2. Checked environmental variables http_proxy and https_proxy (http://proxyserver.internal) - they exist
3. Checked my access to data in Snowflake - I have access
4. Reinstalled Power BI
5. Tried to install Snowflake ODBC driver, but it is not visible in the list of my drivers
6. Tried to connect to different warehouses in Snowflake - same issue
7. 'Auto resume' option for my warehouse in on

Could you, please, advise what else can I do?
Thank you.

Comment: "Tried to install Snowflake ODBC driver, but it is not visible in the list of my drivers" . Are you sure if the bit version is same as the machine where the driver is being installed ? As in it could be a case that on a 64 bit machine,32 bit driver is being installed.
Secondly, on this machine with proxy are you able to connect to any other websites? 
Check if the native ODBC connection is working fine without proxy and with proxy and also the odbc logs.

Comment: @Hanna, this looks like a proxy issue. Installing [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) and running it again the JSON produced by [SYSTEM$WHITELIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html) will probably show you what exactly is the issue. If you use a proxy there are several URLs that might need to be whitelisted.